# Как отображать сообщения об ошибках в консоли CLion так, чтобы их можно было прочесть?

Tags: исключения, clion

Написал простую программу с выводом одной фразы. Кириллица в stdout отображалась после того, как преобразовал файл с кодом в кодировку IBM866, сообщения об ошибках продолжают отображаться непонятными символами. Везде установлена кодировка UTF-8, стандарт C90. Что мне еще нужно переделать, чтобы ошибки можно было сразу прочесть, а не через декодер?

```
warning C4047: дг­ЄжЁп: "char *" ®в«Ёз Ґвбп Ї® га®ў­п¬ Є®бўҐ­­®Ј® ®Ўа йҐ­Ёп ®в "char"
warning C4024: gets_s: а §«Ёз­лҐ вЁЇл ¤«п д®а¬ «м­®Ј® Ё д ЄвЁзҐбЄ®Ј® Ї а ¬Ґва®ў 1
error C2065: ch_1: ­Ґ®Ўкпў«Ґ­­л© Ё¤Ґ­вЁдЁЄ в®а
error C2143: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ®вбгвбвўЁҐ ";" ЇҐаҐ¤ "}"
error C2075: "ch": ¤«п Ё­ЁжЁ «Ё§ жЁЁ ваҐЎгҐвбп бЇЁб®Є Ё­ЁжЁ «Ё§ в®а®ў, § Є«озҐ­­л© ў дЁЈга­лҐ бЄ®ЎЄЁ.
```

Comment: Удалите русификацию в студии. Ошибки сразу будут читаемые